# Where can I find ssbdiagnose

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Is there a place where I can get this utility for diagnosing service broker in sql server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ssbdiagnose.exe is a command line application that comes with Microsoft SQL Server 2008.
It usually resides in C:\%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn. The documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934450.aspx).

EDIT: as Greg pointed below, the .exe is usually in the **64 bit** Program Files directory. My bad!

Comment: Thanks for that Rodrigo, I have read the documentation, what I need is somewhere to download the exe from.

Comment: This is a long time ago, but I got stuck because I kept looking in Program Files (x86) directory but it was actually in the 64 bit Program Files Directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is now added as part of SQL Server Management Studio package. Starting SSMS 18.1.

[The SQL Server Diagnose (command-line tool) was added back into the SSMS package.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#whats-new-in-181)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio 18.12.1
It is located in: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7